# two co-integrated series implies that residuals are stationary?

Tags: cointegration, stationarity

I have two series, X & Y. X & Y are co-integrated, which implies that:
Z = a1*X + a2*Y is I(0).
I put Y as function of X:
Y = alpha + beta*X + epsilon

So the combination: Y - beta*X  is always stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as you wrote $a_1x+a_2y$ is stationary, not $y-\beta x$.

Consider, $x_t=t+\varepsilon_t$ and $y_t=1.1t+\epsilon_t$, so you find that $1.1x_t+y_t$ is stationary, i.e. x and y are cointegrated. If you set $z_t=y_t-\beta x_t$ where $\beta=1.2\ne 1.1$ then it's not stationary: $$z_t=-0.1t+u_t$$

In other words not just any linear combo of cointegrated variables is stationary, but a special combination, which you need to find using cointegrated regression tools.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I still don't understand: The only fact I know is that Z=a1*X+a2*Y is I(0), so X and Y are cointegrated, but I don't know if Z is stationary. I think that co-integration don't implies stationarity, or am I wrong?

Comment: @FedericoCaccia, your and my examples are when the series went from I(1) to I(0), so in this case, yes, cointegration means stationary linear combination. However, cointegration could be I(2) to I(1), in which case no, the linear combination is nonstationary, but the lower integration level. In other word, you're right in general case cointegration doesnt mean stationarity

Comment: ok that makes sense! I am a little confused because [here](https://www.quantopian.com/lectures/integration-cointegration-and-stationarity) (in the section "back to order of integration") it says that I(0) does not imply stationarity. Anyway, I would not know how to justify it.